# What type of Application should I choose to be executed daily while having a Global List?

Tags: c#, web-applications, active-directory, windows-services, scheduled-tasks

I want to build an application to email field workers in our company when their passwords have expired. I'll be using some type of C# application while communicating with Active Directory.

I also want to ensure that users do not get emailed every single day/night, as this sounds a bit obnoxious. The idea I have is to create a web application with no UI, and have a global list of emailed users that never gets reset, just gets updated (user gets added when they are emailed, and get removed when their password is no longer expired). So I'll fill that list with a user object containing their samaccountname and the day they were emailed. If they are in the list, I don't want to email them again.

However, upon doing some reading, I found that multiple sources said that having a non-interactive **web** application to be executed on a schedule isn't a good way to do it. Instead, it seemed people were fond of Windows Services, which is something I don't know a lot about.

What would best practice to implement something like this? My ideas might also be completely off. Thanks for any insight.

Edit: New idea - Perhaps using an SQL table would be a better idea than a global list.

Comment: Why not either a windows service or a simple console application that is executed daily by the [task scheduler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/aa383614(v=vs.85).aspx)?

Comment: first off, how is your web app hosted?  If it's in azure, for instance, you might have access to webjobs

Comment: @TimSchmelter - I haven't had much experience with windows services. I see they have a OnStart and OnStop message in Visual Studio - Will my list get reset with the OnStop?

Comment: @SamIam - I'll research webjobs a little more. Can it be used with C#? Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @JonathanPrall I'd only recommend it if you're hosting your site on Azure in the first place, and yes, c# supports it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you're absolutely right about the storage, sql or nosql should do the job.

My advice is to store the the information you have describied in some **database**, this way you will have **secure** and **long-living** storage about the data (scenarios like power-cut, network drop or even simple restart of the server won't lead to loosing the information about the send emails).

Using the **[task scheduler](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc748993(v=ws.11).aspx)** with simple **console application** will be just fine. It sound more close to your needs (executing checks and notification at periods).